# Microphone recording approximately 12x slower than normal in certain applications (new install Ubuntu 16.04.3)

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, audacity

I'm using an analog microphone to record some audio with audacity. When I select the correct microphone and hit record, the bar indicating progress moves ever so slowly. It takes about 12 seconds for it to reach the 1 second mark. If I play the audio it's essentially static but I know that it did come from the microphone. It's not high-pitched.

When I use the microphone with discord there's no problem at all. I've tried adjusting the sampling rate from within audacity but the "speed" at which the progress indicator moves is always the same. The default sample rate is 44100 Hz.

The microphone works fine with audacity on Windows, and as I said works fine in Discord on ubuntu. I have almost no idea what the problem could be, and have little idea how I can even search for it. (currently tried "ubuntu microphone slow"). I don't know what to call this problem to begin with.

Comment: Are you using a low latency kernel?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this reply](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1764965/comments/14) to the corresponding [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1764965) report, you should find your audio device (I used audacity and tried both devices listed, see screenshot.)

[image: audacity recording device menu before the command]

In my case the command required was

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:2,2
```

After that, recording works when you choose *pulse* in Audacity.

---

After restarting Audacity the device you used will no longer be visible

[image: audacity recording device menu after the command]

and there will be a duplicate device in *Settings* > *Sounds*

[image: Gnome sound settings]

Also this fix does not persist a restart. Run this command on login (e.g. using *Startup Application* if you need, or see the [bug reply](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1764965/comments/14) for another solution.